# iptables - router configuration

Tags: router, home-networking, iptables

I have a router that I am customizing settings for.  I want to only allow SSH from the internal network and drop everything else.

This is what I have so far.  I tried it and I had to reset my router in order to connect to it again, so I think I am missing something:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT --match state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT --destination 127.0.0.1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.11.0/24 --protocol tcp  --dport $SSH_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP

iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -s 192.168.11.0/24 --protocol tcp  -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -F OUTPUT
```

Is that a good starting point?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the output `iptables-save`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review and having used these rules for over a month, I think it is fairly safe to say the rules work.  I use -P to set the policy default.  I prefer DROP to REJECT as it uses fewer resources and tells the potential attacker less information.

Walter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the -P in there.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT --destination 127.0.0.1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -s 192.168.11.0/24 -m tcp -p tcp --dport $SSH_PORT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with-icmp-host-prohibited
```

You don't need to use the forward chain, but if this is a script you should still do the flush of all the chains first.

You can choose to use DROP instead of REJECT in the last line if you want.

Comment: Why not `-P`, it sets default chain rule. That's better than adding special rule as last rule. Now if you add additional rules with -A, it'll go after REJECT, and therefore it's useless. That's not the case with `-P`

Comment: Fair point. I also use -P on occasion, but the explicit last rule serves me well, and also means iptables returns ICMP unreachable (which helps in my environment, where I have both system-level firewalling and switch ACL firewalls that do not return ICMP unreachable). When I add rules, I use -I <chain> <rule number>, possibly because I'm a masochist. :)

Comment: I prefer DROP as it uses slightly less resources than reject since no reply is sent.

Comment: If this is a router, I need the forward chain right?